# menu is not looking as expected

Tags: css

I have this site : http://test.tamarawobben.nl
Now the menu at the top is not looking well.
I must look like this image: http://test.tamarawobben.nl/screenshot.png.

Who can help me figure out what went wrong here ?

Roelof

Edit 1 : Is there a way all the submenus are even big. Now the width is depending of the text.
I know I can use width but I think I then break the layout because ít's never use width.
And I'm not the downvoter.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

#### Give this css:

```
#header ul li {
    padding: 0 1em;
    font-size: 10px;
}
```

#### Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: I see what you mean. But still a see a piece of black at both sides of the menu.

Comment: you've put your `ul` inside a `h1` tag, which has padding applied to it. put the `ul` directly after the `</h1>`

Comment: Yea, put the `ul` directly after the `</h1>`.

Comment: The solution of Praveen works fine. Change the last <h1> to </h1>

Answer (score 1):

use this css for ul #nav;

```
#nav{
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;}
```